# Bridge multiple BlackBerry connections to increase bandwidth

Tags: networking, blackberry, network-programming

I am interested in doing something like "[link aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)" over the data connection on multiple BlackBerry devices.
What tools are available to do this?  If I write this myself, how do I balance out the data across the different devices?  Can this be done entirely on the remote side - with just the BlackBerries and a computer, or will I need a server to connect all the data back together?

Comment: Not even remotely a programming question.

Comment: @Andrew So you don't understand that Tether is a program, or that I am looking for a program solution to allow this program to run multiple instances?  Perhaps you are not a programmer?

Comment: Though I think you could rephrase in a way that is more stackoverflow approrpriate, such as asking about algorithms and libraries that might help you do this, instead of what looks like a request for COTS software.

Comment: I've edited your question to be more appropriate for stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For data tethering, the easiest way is to play with routing table.  For example, you have 3 BlackBerries connected to one computer, and they will be shown as three different network adapters.

Now you can design your routing metrics by dividing IP address range.  Say, BB1 routes traffic to and from 1.1.1.1 to 70.255.255.255, BB2 routes 71.0.0.1 to 142.255.255.255, and all other traffic goes through BB3.  Ideally the three devices will have balanced load.

If you want to have something like trunking, i.e. triple bandwidth connecting to same IP/port, that will be challenging, because you're handling a three IP to one problem and you have no control over the IP addresses assigned to the BlackBerries (your ISP assign them to you).  In that case, having your own server as a relay makes sense, but I seriously doubt the usefulness.  Switch to [LTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_Advanced) will be a much easier choice in this case.